# Populate SQL column with a sequential number

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio

I am new to SQL, I want to populate a column using an SQL query in Microsoft Visual Studio where I have a sequential number from 1 to 24. However these numbers are populated with 2 conditions: group by Year, Month.

Highlighted in blue is the output I want:

[image]

Note: Month is represented in integers. For example 1 = January.

Current query:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[upload_STS_data] (
[result_count]  INT          NOT NULL,
[username]      VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
[year]          INT          NOT NULL,
[month]         INT          NOT NULL,
[Users_acct_id] INT          NOT NULL,
[upload_id]     INT          IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([upload_id] ASC),
CONSTRAINT [fk_upload_STS_data_Users1] FOREIGN KEY ([Users_acct_id]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Users] ([acct_id])
);    


GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [fk_upload_STS_data_Users1_idx]
    ON [dbo].[upload_STS_data]([Users_acct_id] ASC);
```

How can I do this?

Comment: done :) @GordonLinoff

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
select dense_rank() over (order by year, month)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want unique No. for each rows, you may want to use the `ROW_NUMBER()` function which would assign unique number if no `PARTITION BY` is given inside the `OVER` clause -

```
SELECT [year] AS [Year]
      , [month] AS [Month]
      , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [year], [month]) AS [No.]
FROM [dbo].[upload_STS_data];
```

Note: You might use **upload_id** or **Users_acct_id** in the `ORDER BY` depending on your need.